# using =+ on variable then get undefined variable while the variable answer is correct in PHP

Tags: php

I made a loop then sum it into variable $jumlahtotal, what I confuse is the value in $jumlahtotal is true when I try to echo it, but I getting *undefined variable* error on this $jumlahtotal

Note : i tried declare it outside the foreach but still getting error undefined variable;

here's my code :

```
$total = 0;
    $totalberat = 0;
    if (isset($_SESSION['items'])) {
    foreach ($_SESSION['items'] as $key => $val) {
    $query = mysqli_query($koneksi, "select * from barang where br_id = '$key'");
        $data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        $jumlah_harga = $data['br_hrg']*$val;
        $total += $jumlah_harga;
        $berat = $data['brt_brg']*$val;
        $totalberat += $berat;
        $jumlahtotal += $val;
}}
?>
```

Comment: declare it outside the loop with the value of 0.

Comment: @MarkVincentManjac it work, I just know it must declared as 0 first before sum it, thx

Answer (score 1):

Some tips:

Start declaring $jumlahtotal=0 above $totalberat.

```
$total = 0;
$totalberat = 0;
$jumlahtotal = 0;
```

Validate the value of $val before adding its value to $jumlahtotal.

```
if (is_int($val)) {
    $jumlahtotal += $val;
} else {
    die('$val not int');
}
```

If its all okay, debug the code and check the code is reaching the '$jumlahtotal += $val;' sentence and debug it.

```
$jumlahtotal += $val;
var_dump($jumlahtotal);
```

It should help you to find the issue.